# Which other scriptures say that inter-caste marriages can give better children?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, caste-system, marriage, yudhisthira

In a discussion between Yudhishthira and Yaksha, Yudhishthira says that children from inter-caste couples can be treated better compared to the same caste couple if the inter-caste couple undergoes [some purification rules](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/46276)

> **Swayambhuba Manu has declared, that the mixed castes are to be
> regarded as better than the (other) classes, if having gone through
> the ceremonies of purification**, the latter do not conform to the rules
> of good conduct, O excellent snake! Whosoever now conforms to the
> rules of pure and virtuous conduct, him have I, ere now, designated as
> a Brahmana.'

Are there any other scriptures that explicitly contain the same fact?